# Advise on how to share excel with other users

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, excel, vba

I am looking for advice on how to resolve the following issue.

As part of a volunteering project I have automated an Excel spreadsheet using VBA. I have written a lot of code that includes user forms and classes.

I would like to allow other volunteer to access the spreadsheet and make some changes to the content (just the content, not the VBA code). Their editing may have to be done through VBA user forms.

The easiest way to allow this is to install a remote control software (like Team Viewer) and distribute the access codes to the volunteers. Unfortunately this would not be the optimal solution for security and continuity reasons.

Does anyone know a better way to allow users to edit a spreadsheet from remote that does not cost a fortune?

Comment: You posted the question in a site about SharePoint. Does that mean you can use SharePoint to store the file? If so, is there a SharePoint related issue?

Comment: Thank you Teylyn, I am not familiar with Sharepoint at all, but I initially posted the question on StackExchange and was invited to post it here. From some research I did, it appears it might be possible for users to collaborate on an Excel spreadsheet that has been copied to Sharepoint. However, it is unclear to me whether the collaboration extends to running quite elaborated VBA codes on Sharepoint. So, that is why I am asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While it is possible to share Excel files on SharePoint, and view these files with the Excel Web App, it is not possible to run VBA code in a file that only shows in the browser.

In order to execute VBA code, the SharePoint user would need to (download and) open the file in desktop Excel. Some security mechanisms may actually prevent the Excel file from running the VBA code unless it is a trusted file.

It very much depends on the situation, user permissions, etc. Basically, any user with permissions to edit the file can open it in edit mode on the desktop and save it back to the server.

You may want to enable check in / check out to make sure that the file can only be edited by one person at a time.

There are many factors that need to match for this scenario to be successful. In other words: There are plenty of aspects where this scenario can fall over because some detail does not perform to the required standards.

It's not a simple case of "follow the steps".

Comment: Thank you Teylyn. Do you have suggestions on alternative solutions to the problem? (I am starting to think that using Citrix may be the way to go).